# Translate order email

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order, email-templates, email-translation

I want to translate the totals row in Magento 2 in the order e-mail.

The strings are: Shipping & Handling / Grand Total.
I edited both in the i18N file, but it doesn't change in the email. I have flushed the cache and runned a reindex.

I can't find the template wherein this string is located. If I know where that one is, maybe I'll find the right words to translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the code wherein the strings are placed:
`vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order`

I translated them, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it in your theme in a csv with a translation dictionary

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html